# How do I detect when FlatList has rendered all items and actually scrolled to bottom?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm passing a very long array into a FlatList.

FlatList dynamically loads more content as you reach the bottom.

I have a ListFooterComponent that indicates whether the user is about to see more data.

How can I know when the FlatList has truly rendered all items and therefore has reached actual bottom of scroll? Then this footer component will show something like "You're at the end of the list!"

Comment: that dynamically load more content doesn't actually automatically fetch/request new data, your server should tell you when there's no more data to return and only then you can update your UI/footer component to show "you're at the end of the list"

Comment: FlatList has a property `onEndReached` which takes a function to be called when the user reaches the end of the list. You can pass a function and inside of it test if there’s no more items to add and display your message in footer.

Answer (score 7):

FlatList component has a callback function that is called when the list reaches the end or the specified threshold.

```
<FlatList
    ...
   onEndReached={() => {console.log('list ended');}}
/>
```

See [onEndReached](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist#onendreached) for details.

Comment: I have a small related question.. how does flatlist know it has actually reached the end? Does it detect the data not getting updated or the new data being empty?

Comment: onEndReached event occurs when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list, it isn't fired when the all items are rendered